# Delphi [find declaration] using OTA

Tags: delphi, toolsapi, otapi

I am working on an IDE expert in D10 Seattle, and can't figure out how to access "Find Declaration" (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>) in code.  I need to use it in my own keybinding so I can drop a breadcrumb first.

If it's not available, is there a workaround by somehow accessing the delphi context menu?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Monte